# Primefaces datatable header alignment with scrollbar

Tags: primefaces, scrollbar

I'm facing a strange behaviour of Primefaces (v.5.1) Datatable.
I have a datatable with srollable=true:

```
<p:dataTable var="_udf" value="#{unitaDiFornituraList}" scrollHeight="350"  liveScroll="true" scrollRows="20" 
    scrollable="true" id="risultati" widgetVar="risultati">
```

When there are lots of items the scrollbar is shown and the header is correctly aligned:
[image: scroll]

When there are up to 5 items the scrollbar doesn't appear and the header correctly hide the gap on the right for the scrollbar:
[image: no scroll]

The strange thing is when I have more than 5 items but not enough to show the scrollbar. In this case the header shows the gap and thus it's not aligned:
[image: wrong alignment]

Any ideas? 
Thank you

Comment: Did you try a newer release? Check the issue list? Releasenotes? Blog? I'm almost 100% sure this was fixed

Comment: I found this issue [link](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6993), it says Fixed but I have the latest release (5.2) and it is not.

Comment: Any custom css on the datatable?

Comment: No. I've tried to change theme as well and it makes no difference.